# Multiple sliders on one page?

Tags: jquery, slider, jssor

is it possible to have two sliders with two different sets of options, one horizontal and one vertical in one page?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
var optionsVertical = {
      $AutoPlay: true,
      $DragOrientation: 2,
      $PlayOrientation: 2
      };
 var optionsHorizontal = {
           $AutoPlay: true
           };
    var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$('slider1_container', optionsHorizontal);
    var jssor_slider2 = new $JssorSlider$('slider2_container', optionsVertical);
});
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Please just try.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I can't make it work if I have two different sets of options defined. If both uses the same option, it works really fine. Like if I set optionsHorizontal to both jssor_slider1 and jssor_slider2. However, I really need jssor to be able to cater for both... Am I doing it wrong? Is there any other approach to this?

Comment: I was able to make it work just now. For you guys who might experience the same thing, you can refer to my saved pen at codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JfhFc

Comment: You should place arrow navigator skin and bullet navigator skin inside 'slider1_container' or 'slider2_container'

Comment: thanks for that. i am trying to add $DisplayPieces = n, where n is a number greater than 1 for the vertical slider but it doesn't seem to display it correctly...

Comment: You'd manually set $SlideWidth to (width of 'slides' container) / n

Comment: If $SlideWidth is 200, and n is 3, the width of 'slides' container is 600px then. Please see 'demos-jquery\carousel-slider.source.html'. In addition, if you set $SlideSpacing, then you need to increase width of 'slides' container.

Comment: that's perfect! thanks for your help and very quick response!